# Convert string paths directory structure into to JSON object with Java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, recursion

I am trying to create a nested tree view with Custom Pojo **Node** in Spring MVC,
the input that I have from the JSch library after exec `command1="find $(pwd) -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -path '*/\\.*' | sort"` will be a list of Strings which contains Absolute Paths for files under the current working directory, as shown in the example below.

```
`List<String> paths = [
"/Sample Dir/sample.cpp",
"/Sample Dir/New Folder",
"/Sample Dir/New Folder/Sample.txt"];`
```

I need to create a hierarchical JSON object with the following Model:

```
public class Node {
    private String name;
    private String location;
    private List<Node> children;
    }
```

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm, how to represent file paths as a Node class which gives the below JSON.
Below is the code which I tried, which is having some problems which i'm unable to figure out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class DemoMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Node root = new Node("/");
        AddNode("/Sample Dir/sample.cpp", root);
        AddNode("/Sample Dir/New Folder", root);
        AddNode("/Sample Dir/New Folder/Sample.txt", root);
        AddNode("/Sample Dir/New Folder/demo.txt", root);
        ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper(); 
        String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(root);
        System.out.println(jsonStr);
    }

    public static Node AddNode(String filePath, Node rootNode) {
        // convenience method. this creates the queue that we need for recursion from
        // the filepath for you
        if(filePath.startsWith("/")) {
            filePath = filePath.split("/",2)[1];
        }
        List<String> tokenList = Arrays.asList(filePath.split("/"));
        tokenList.remove(" ");
        // if you split a folder ending with / it leaves an empty string at the end and
        // we want to remove that
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(tokenList.get(tokenList.size() - 1))) {
            tokenList.remove(tokenList.size() - 1);
        }

        PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        queue.addAll(tokenList);
        return AddNode(queue, rootNode);
    }

    private static Node AddNode(Queue<String> tokens, Node rootNode) {
        // base case -> node wasnt found and tokens are gone :(
        if (tokens == null || tokens.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        // get current token, leaving only unsearched ones in the tokens object
        String current = tokens.remove();

        // create node if not already exists
        Node foundNode = rootNode.FindNode(current);
        if (foundNode != null) {
            // node exists! recurse
            return AddNode(tokens, foundNode);
        } else {
            // node doesnt exist! add it manually and recurse
            Node newNode = new Node(current);
            rootNode.getChildren().add(newNode);
            return AddNode(tokens, newNode);
        }
    }
}

class Node {
    public String name;
    public List<Node> children;
    public String location;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Node() {
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
    
    public Node(String fileName) {
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
        this.name = fileName;
    }
    public Node FindNode(String data) {
        if (this.children == null || this.children.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        // check Node list to see if there are any that already exist
        return this.children.stream().filter(node -> node.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(data)).findFirst().orElse(null);
        // .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Data.equalIgnoreCase(data));
    }

}
```

Below is the Output i'm getting:

```
{"name":"/","children":[{"name":"Sample Dir","children":[{"name":"sample.cpp","children":[],"location":null}],"location":null},{"name":"New Folder","children":[{"name":"Sample Dir","children":[{"name":"Sample.txt","children":[],"location":null},{"name":"demo.txt","children":[],"location":null}],"location":null}],"location":null}],"location":null}
```

> Desired Output is as below,

```
 [
  {
    "name": "Sample Dir",
    "location": "Sample Dir",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "New Folder",
        "location": "Sample Dir/New Folder",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Sample.txt",
            "location": "Sample Dir/New Folder/Sample.txt",
            "children": "null"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "sample.cpp",
        "location": "Sample Dir/sample.cpp",
        "children": "null"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Could you help me to where I'm wrong? Any leads are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the specific issue?

Comment: Is the problem is creating the Node based on the files, or making json based on the Nodes?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not able to figure out, how to  create node recursively after splitting each String for "/"

Comment: @Ofek I'm trying to figure out the algorithm, to convert list of Stings as Node class, but unable to

Comment: Please post [mre]

Comment: @c0der, thanks for the quick response, but this is the bare min example that I can post as it contains a Pojo, with the main class.

Comment: While it might be **M** it is not **R**. It doesn't even compile. MRE should be copy-paste-run.

Comment: @c0der, I have added the working code, can you please help me out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're using PriorityQueue which will return the tokens in ascending order as no comparator is provided. In a priority queue the poll/remove method will remove the smallest element (depends on comparator) first. Instead you should use LinkedList which will work on FIFO principle.
Update this

```
PriorityQueue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<String>();
```

To this

```
Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>(tokenList);
```

This should give you the desired output except for the location for which the logic is missing.